# Error with siunitx package, \pi as a number, and detect-all

Tags: siunitx

I have a problem when using the `siunitx` package, specifically when using the `detect-all` option and trying to use the `\pi` symbol as a number.

Minimum working example (MWE) below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

This works happily: \SI{2\pi e15}{\radian\per\second}

\sisetup{detect-all,}
But this gives an error : \SI{2\pi e15}{\radian\per\second}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: What does `\sisetup{detect-all,}` do?

Comment: `\sisetup{detect-all}` is an option for the `siunitx` package, which essentially makes all usage of numbers and units with the package "fit in" with the text around them.

So while `\SI{10}{m}` will normally use whatever Maths font is loaded when used in the middle of a standard text section (which looks odd, in my opinion), it will instead change the font to the standard font if `\sisetup{detect-all}` is enabled.

Comment: @bth-root - The explanation "it will instead change the font to the standard font" is not quite right. Rather, it's the *current font* -- which need not be a "standard" font -- that'll be used. What is "current" is determined at the start of the operation of the `\SI` macro.

Comment: @Mico - Thanks for the clarification. Mine was definitely a layperson's explanation - it's good to have the proper description down for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `\sisetup{detect-all}`, `siunitx` requires the entire `\SI` directive to be in math mode in order to process `\pi` correctly, i.e., it requires you to run

```
$\SI{2\pi e15}{\radian\per\second}$
```

On p. 5 of the package's user guide, one finds:

> By default, all text is typeset in the current upright math font. This can be changed by setting the appropriate options: `\sisetup{detect-all}` will use the current font for typesetting.

What this means is that if `detect-all` is in force, `siunitx` does not *automatically* use a math font to generate the output of `\SI` and `\si`. Thus the need for the `$` symbols.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{XCharter,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{2\pi e15}{\radian\per\second}

\sisetup{detect-all}
$\SI{2\pi e15}{\radian\per\second}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a follow on from this, as I wanted to avoid using a math font in the main text of my document: a once-off, slightly ugly fix was to input the "2pi" and "times" symbol separately from the rest of the `SI` macro, with appropriate spacing, as follows:

`2\textpi\,$\times$\,\SI{e15}{\radian\per\second}`


(Doing so required loading the `\textgreek` package for the pi symbol.)

Answer (score 0):

The siunitx documentation suggests the following approach to add more valid symbols like pi in the section "Symbolic 'digits'":

`\sisetup{input-digits = 0123456789\pi}`

> ## 9.15 Symbolic ‘digits’
>
> In some cases you may want to use ‘digits’ which do not fall within the usual set
> 0123456789. This can be done by setting the input-digits option, but bearing in
> 68mind that this will affect (prevent) for example rounding.
>
> \sisetup{input-digits = 0123456789\pi}%
> \num{4\pi e-7}
> 4π × 10−7
>
> Each extra entry should be a single token, and should either have a definition which
> is safe in both math and text mode, or should only be used when the output mode
> is known. It may be necessary to make some tokens robust using etoolbox for this to
> work, for example
>
> \robustify\dots
> \sisetup{input-digits = 0123456789\dots}%
> \qty{0,4066\dots}{\metre\squared}
> 0.406 6 ... m^2